# Trouble Implementing Rijndael MixColums in Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, rijndael

I am trying to implement the MixColumns algorithm for AES in python, but I am having some trouble. Here is my code:

```
def multiply(b,a):

    if b == 1:
        return a
    if b == 2:
         return ((a<<1)&0xff)^0x1b

    if b == 3:
        return (((a<<1)&0xff)^0x1b)^a
s_mat1 = [np.copy(s) for s in s_mat]
        for i in range(len(s_mat)):
            for j in range(len(s_mat[i])):

                s_mat[i][j] = multiply(mx_col[i][0],s_mat1[0][j])^multiply(mx_col[i][1],s_mat1[1][j])^multiply(mx_col[i][2],s_mat1[2][j])^multiply(mx_col[i][3],s_mat1[3][j])
```

here `s_mat` is the state matrix and `mx_col` is the mixcolumn matrix. I tried this code for this example:
[image]
However my code is giving different answer from the given. here is the answer given by my code:

```
[['ba', '84', 'e8', '1b'], ['6e', 'a4', '8d', '5b'], ['f4', '96', '6', '7d'], ['61', '29', 'e', '46']]
```

The first row is coming correct. But why are the other rows coming wrong? what mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For
[image]
there is a case distinction which has not been considered in the code: The `XOR` with `0x1b` is only performed for `a > 127`, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2403). This changes the cases `b == 2` and `b == 3`:

```
def multiply(b,a):
    if b == 1:
        return a
    tmp = (a<<1) & 0xff
    if b == 2:
        return tmp if a < 128 else tmp^0x1b
    if b == 3:
        return tmp^a if a < 128 else (tmp^0x1b)^a
```

With this change the expected result is obtained.

Comment: thanks, that worked. also, why isn't there any Rijndael's implementation like the one I did with ifs. I found different implementations none were like that. most I found were more complex. even the one given on Wikipedia in C and C# has forloops in it. is there a reason to implement it in the way given or mine is fine with the changes you suggested?

Comment: In [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-solve-mixcolumns/2403#2403) answer the multiplication in the MixColumns step is well described. As far as I can see, this corresponds to your implementation with the changes. The test case is also correct. Maybe the other solutions include several steps of the algorithm (MixColumns is only one step) or a more general solution is implemented (MixColumns is a special case of GF(2^8) multiplication, using only the values 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: @ShantanuShinde - One more thing: In your question/comment you sometimes refer to the algorithm as AES, sometimes as Rijndael. Please note that AES and Rijndael are different algorithms (AES is a special case of Rijndael), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_ciphers), with correspondingly different implementations. This could also be a reason for the differences mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I said AES because I am using the Rijndael mix columns algorithm for the mixcolumn step of AES. and this is the implementation I was referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Implementation_example

Comment: @ShantanuShinde - Both linked codes calculate one column, your code four (and is therefore more AES-specific, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/49981)). Beyond that, I can't see a functional difference. The C# code is a bit more complex, since it (as already assumed) implements GF(2^8) multiplication more generally (but this has no influence on the result).

Comment: Ya, there is no function difference. In the mean time my code wasn't working, I tried both codes in Python and both were giving correct result

Answer (score -1):

For decryption, we can use this code, which uses topaco's code and uses perpetual multiplication for calculating for 9,11,13 and 14,
we can rewrite 14 as ((2+1)*2+1)*2 so it's equivalent code would be (multiply(2,multiply(2,multiply(2,a)^a)^a)):

```
def multiply(b,a):
if b == 1:
    return a
tmp = (a<<1) & 0xff
if b == 2:
    return tmp if a <= 127 else tmp^0x1b
if b == 3:
    return tmp^a if a <= 127 else (tmp^0x1b)^a
if b== 9:
    return multiply(2,multiply(2,multiply(2,a)))^a
if b== 11:
    return multiply(2,multiply(2,multiply(2,a))^a)^a
if b==13:
    return multiply(2,multiply(2,(multiply(2,a)^a)))^a
if b==14:
    return multiply(2,multiply(2,multiply(2,a)^a)^a)
```

Comment: Yes, `a >= 127` in my answer is a typo, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137113/9014097) more detailed answer. Fixed. However, a comment would have been nice. Thanks anyway.