# AES MixColumns with Python

Tags: python, aes

I am trying to create an aes mix column function in python. But the result is not as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Here I test on the first column.

```
[2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 136, 153, 170, 187, 204, 221, 238, 255]

print((0*2)^(17*3)^(34*1)^(51*1))
print((0*1)^(17*2)^(34*3)^(51*1))
print((0*1)^(17*1)^(34*2)^(51*3))
print((0*3)^(17*1)^(34*1)^(51*2))
```

The result is as follows:

```
34
119
204
85
```

What I think is the expected result is:

```
34
119
0
85
```

Is the expected result wrong or am I doing wrong?

Comment: 0 is indeed correct and not 204, since this is not an ordinary multiplication, but modulo irreducible polynomial x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2403) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Implementation_example). The latter link also contains implementations that you can port.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the calculation would look like in this case. Could you show me how to change my calculation to get 0 instead of 204? @Topaco

Comment: I' ve posted a possible implementation of the required multiplication, please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the posted code, the multiplication is implemented wrongly. Multiplication is modulo irreducible polynomial x<sup>8</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + x + 1 in the Galois field *GF*(2<sup>8</sup>). This is described in detail in the Wikipedia article [Rijndael MixColumns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns). Here you can also find various implementations. Another, easier to understand description can be found on SO in the accepted answer to the post [How to solve MixColumns?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-solve-mixcolumns).

In the following implementation the multiplication (with 1, 2 and 3) is implemented in the function `gmul()`:

```python
def mixColumns(a, b, c, d):
    printHex(gmul(a, 2) ^ gmul(b, 3) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 1))
    printHex(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 2) ^ gmul(c, 3) ^ gmul(d, 1))
    printHex(gmul(a, 1) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 2) ^ gmul(d, 3))
    printHex(gmul(a, 3) ^ gmul(b, 1) ^ gmul(c, 1) ^ gmul(d, 2))
    print()

def gmul(a, b):
    if b == 1:
        return a
    tmp = (a << 1) & 0xff
    if b == 2:
        return tmp if a < 128 else tmp ^ 0x1b
    if b == 3:
        return gmul(a, 2) ^ a

def printHex(val):
    return print('{:02x}'.format(val), end=' ')

# test vectors from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Test_vectors_for_MixColumn()
mixColumns(0xdb, 0x13, 0x53, 0x45) # 0x8e 0x4d 0xa1 0xbc
mixColumns(0xf2, 0x0a, 0x22, 0x5c) # 0x9f 0xdc 0x58 0x9d
mixColumns(0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01) # 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 
mixColumns(0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6) # 0xc6 0xc6 0xc6 0xc6 
mixColumns(0xd4, 0xd4, 0xd4, 0xd5) # 0xd5 0xd5 0xd7 0xd6 
mixColumns(0x2d, 0x26, 0x31, 0x4c) # 0x4d 0x7e 0xbd 0xf8

# example from question
mixColumns(0, 17, 34, 51) # 0x22 0x77 0x00 0x55 = 34 119 0 85
```

with the output:

```
8e 4d a1 bc 
9f dc 58 9d 
01 01 01 01 
c6 c6 c6 c6 
d5 d5 d7 d6 
4d 7e bd f8 
22 77 00 55
```

The first 6 lines are the results to the [test vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Test_vectors_for_MixColumn()) from the Wikipedia article. The last line corresponds to the example from the posted question: 0x22, 0x77, 0x00, 0x55 or 34, 119, 0, 85 decimal. As you can see, the third value is 0 not 204.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are doing wrong : answer of `(0*1)^(17*1)^(34*2)^(51*3)` is `204`.

- `(0*1)  = 00000000`
- `(17*1) = 00010001`
- `(34*2) = 01000100`
- `(51*3) = 10011001`

Then applying XOR operator on these lines result in : `11001100`.

XOR operator sets each bit to 1 if only one of two bits is 1. That means for each bits, if  there is an odd number of 1, the resulting bit will be set to 1.

Please explain how you computed 0 if this answer doesn't help you to understand why the answer is `204`.